# Stop PowerPoint from disabling Power Save Mode

Tags: command-line, power-management, microsoft-powerpoint, screensaver

I have a PowerPoint presentation that I am launching using the command `powerpnt /s "filepath"`.  This presentation runs as a screensaver on our workstations and runs just fine.  The problem is that as long as the PowerPoint is running the computer will not enter power save mode.  Normally this would be the preffered and expected method of operation but since this is a screensaver I would like for PowerPoint to NOT disable power save mode.

Is there any way to allow power save mode to kick in while the PowerPoint presentation is running but *only* for this presentation?

**My Solution**
Following the advice of one of the answers I found directions from Microsoft which tell you how to put a system into suspend mode from the command line, so this will work for me.  Link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:** Take a Program that for 10 years people have been trying to stop from going on standby :-) and get it to allow standby.  ok, some thoughts.

**Batch** The exact operation that you desire.  Your already starting the powerpoint using CMD functions, so set a "Timeout" function in the batch, then set a "TaskEnd" function to close the program (or only have one big non looping presentation).  Then run a "Standby" command right after that.  . . Knowing the exact operating system is important to making a batch with the least additional tools needed.

---

Other ideas that probably would not be suitable.

**Stop powerpoint and allow standby:** 
Kick the powerpoint off after some time, say after it has run for 5-10 minutes, then allow normal standby to occur. Problem, after the power point finnaly stops the system will still delay until it goes into standby based on the timings for power.

Simple way to do the above, do not set the presenation to loop infinate, instead have a few loops of the presentation IN the one file, so it runs a few times and then stops itself.

**Start it using Task Scheduler:** Set the Program to start by using the Windows Task Scheduler and Idle trigger, and have it be told to end using the "stop program if still running time" in task scheduler. Problem same as above , where is the instant standby.

**Run a Program as a Screensaver** there are utility programs that will run any program "as a screensaver" Assumption, if it is run as a screensaver it is possible that it would act LIKE a screensaver, and eventually close down and allow standby. Problem, most of them will activate a program, but cannot control what the program does. it is possible one might work, but I doubt it.

Comment: I am running this as an actual screensaver, most of my code is in C# but I call powerpoint using a standard commandline type call so I thought I would give superuser a shot.  I can vouch that even when running as a screensaver powerpoint still manages to override the power management settings.  I think i'll try your idea and tell Windows to enter standby after a set period of time (maybe I can even read the actual value from windows registry or something).

Comment: registry, hmm, have you seen "PowerRequestOverride"? supposedly it is for drivers that dont behave?  http://iboyd.net/index.php/2010/05/16/windows-7-power-management-fixing-pc-insomnia/

Comment: Happened across this article that shows how to kick in suspend state via the command line :) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555569 I think I'll take this approach.

Comment: I was going to suggest `PShutdown` for kicking in suspend state.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any direct way of setting this, but there's a couple of workarounds:

1. Save the slides out to bitmaps, and store them in a directory - then use the normal photo screensaver that comes with Windows.  Microsoft's page on this is [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/powerpoint-help/create-a-screen-saver-from-slides-HA001079773.aspx).  This is the best option, IMO, because it's relatively clean.
2. If you're really stuck on using native PowerPoint, you could try [this utility](http://www.adingod.com/kiosk.html) which purports to do what you want, although not selectively (it will probably kick in during other PowerPoints)
3. If that doesn't do it for you then another option would be use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).  You'd set up a scheduled task (which is run after x minutes of inactivity), and the task would run this command line:

   nircmd.exe monitor off